# Xamarin: iOS remote notification has no sound

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I've been banging my head for a few days now trying to figure this out.

I followed this article to setup local notifications for both iOS and Android
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications

I also added push notification service for both platforms, on Android everything works fine (both local and remote push notifications).

For iOS, the article doesn't mention that you have to add a line of code to make the notification alert with sound, so I modified the `SendNotification` method to have the `content` object like this

```
        var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent()
        {
            Title = title,
            Subtitle = "",
            Body = message,
            Badge = 1,
            Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default
        };
```

Now the notifications have sound on iOS for both local and remote notifications, but when the app is closed (in background) the notification still shows without sound.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code in the AppDelegate.cs file :

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    ...

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
    {
        // you could register different settings
        var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, null
            );   
        app.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings);
    }
    ...   
}
```

The code above ask for the permisson to display notifications and we could register different settings as we like. So the following code in Intialize method in [Xamarin LocalNotifications sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/LocalNotifications) is not needed any more as well as the bool *hasNotificationsPermission* .

```
public void Initialize()
{
    // the following code could be deleted
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) =>
        {
            hasNotificationsPermission = approved;
        });
    }
```

Hope it works for you.